# How to prevent print multiple times in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I created a loop for fetch total amount of items from database. I am using EJS and this is my code shown below.

```
       <h2>Summary</h2>
         <% if(typeof items.cart!=="undefined"){
           var amount = 0;  %>
         <% items.cart.forEach(function(file) {
                  amount +=parseInt(file.price); %>
           <ul class="summary-table" id="summary-table">
               <li><span>subtotal:</span> <span><%= amount %></span></li>
               <li><span>delivery:</span> <span>Free</span></li>
               <li><span>discount:</span> <span></span></li>
               <li><span>total:</span> <span><%= amount %></span></li>
           </ul>

           <% }); %>
        <%  } %>
```

I got the total amount of items. But **Summary** will print multiple times when price add into total amount. 
[image]

any tips to prevent them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<ul>` tag appears to be inside the forEach loop, so it's printed for each element of `items.cart`.
I'd recommend calculating the total value somewhere other than in the template and using the template only for rendering.

I'm not familiar with EJS, but you can try this:

```
<h2>Summary</h2>
<% if (typeof items.cart !== "undefined") {
var amount = 0;  %>
    <% items.cart.forEach(function (file) {
    amount += parseInt(file.price); }); %>
        <ul class="summary-table" id="summary-table">
            <li><span>subtotal:</span> <span><%= amount %></span></li>
            <li><span>delivery:</span> <span>Free</span></li>
            <li><span>discount:</span> <span></span></li>
            <li><span>total:</span> <span><%= amount %></span></li>
        </ul>
<%  } %>
```